# How to split an XML file (on specific N node) while conserving a header and a footer with Python?

Tags: python, xml, split, nodes

I am new to Python and I don't know where to start with the solution of my problem.

Here is what I need to do: Read an XML file from a folder and split it on multiple XML files (in another folder) regarding a specific repetitive node (that would be input by the user) while keeping the header (what comes before that node) and the footer (what comes after the node).

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog catalogName="cat1" catalogType="bestsellers">
   <headerNode node="1">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </headerNode>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <footerNode node="2">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </footerNode>
</catalog>
```

So the purpose whould be to have 3 XML files (because we have 3 instances of "book" node) having the "headerNode" + 1 "book" + "footerNode".

The first file would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog catalogName="cat1" catalogType="bestsellers">
   <headerNode node="1">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </headerNode>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <footerNode node="2">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </footerNode>
</catalog>
```

The only constraint is that it needs to be done with "ElementTree" and not "lxml" library (because lxml is not included in the production dependencies).

EDIT: So here is the code based on the answer from "MK Ultra".

For now I modified it to pass two parameters to the script (first one is the name of the XML file without extension and second is the split node), and now I read the XML and generate the XML files on the same folder than the script. (and I use an index in the loop to name the folder)

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

# Get the current directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
# Load the xml
doc = ET.parse(r"%s/%s.xml" % (cwd,sys.argv[1]))
root = doc.getroot()
# Get the header element
header = root.find("headerNode")
# Get the footer element
footer = root.find("footerNode")
# loop over the books and create the new xml file
for idx,book in enumerate(root.findall(sys.argv[2])):
    top = ET.Element(root.tag)
    top.append(header)
    top.append(book)
    top.append(footer)
    out_book = ET.ElementTree(top)
    # the output file name will be the ID of the book
    out_path = "%s/%s_%s.xml" % (cwd,sys.argv[1],idx)
    out_book.write(open(out_path, "wb"))
```

How can I make the "headerNode"/"footerNode" part generic? By this I mean that it would be "book" or something else like "novel", "paper", etc. The correct value would only be known by the user of the script (which is not me obviously) when running it.

EDIT2: Just modified the original file to add attributes to the "catalog" node because I cannot copy the attributes while creating the splitted files.

Comment: This is the _start_ of a good question, but it would be better to work on something and _then_ show the code. I am worried that if someone does your work for you, we'll not get to see your code, since there will seem to be no value in providing it.

Comment: @halfer you're totally right ! Actually i would have provided a code if it wasn't such an urgent matter on a language that is new to me !
I just added to my question the code (using the response of MK Ultra) with a slight modification.

Comment: @Parfait i'm not the same user.. :)

Comment: @halfer just provided the code ! (based on the answers) For now i am thinking about how to make the "headerNode"/"footerNode" part generic(for more details i wrote aboute it in the comments below)  and how to implement the exceptions handling for the multiple error cases (no/wrong input by the user, folder/Xmlfile cannot be found, splitted files cannot be created, etc..).

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. A couple of tips: (a) in your update, it seems you would like more of an answer. I can't tell, but if this is essentially a different question, it may be better to accept an existing answer and present a new question instead. You can continue here though if you believe it is really part of the same original question.

Comment: (b) In any post, please don't refer to "comments below" - comments are frequently deleted by moderators, they are meant to be temporary. Please replace that phrase in your question with the detail you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: Thx for the feedback ! I edited to make it clearer.. hope it's ok now. And i removed the exception handling part as it should be in another questions like you suggested. So, i'm gonna work a little bit on that generic part before closing my question. Have a good day !

Comment: I've edited again to make the question a bit more direct, hope I captured it correctly. In terms of making `headerNode/footerNode` more generic, what do you mean, and what have you tried? Also, does your title need updating based on the new state of the question?

Comment: (I did not see your message to me, since you forgot to add `@halfer` to notify me - please always do this, unless replying under a post I have made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm goes as follows,

- parse your xml file and get your existing root
- with that, form the base for for all books - that has the catalog with header and footer - new_root.
- Now, iterate through the root tag to get all element with tag 'book'
- Then, insert the book element to your new_root and write it to a file - here I've written to a file with name same as your id!

```
#question 2 - tag name as input from user!
tag_name=raw_input("Enter tag name:")
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree,parse,Element
root = parse('sample.xml').getroot()
new_root=Element(root.tag)
#question 1 - multiple header and footer!
new_root.extend(root.findall('.//headerNode'))
new_root.extend(root.findall('.//footerNode'))
for elem in root:
    if elem.tag == tag_name:
        new_root.insert(1,elem)
        #question 3 - write output to file!
        ElementTree(new_root).write(open('path/to/folder'+elem.get('id')+'.xml', 'wb'))
        new_root.remove(elem)
```

**Sample Output:**

**File Name**: bk101.xml

```
<catalog>
   <headerNode node="1">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </headerNode>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <footerNode node="2">
      <param1>value1</param1>
      <param2>value2</param2>
   </footerNode>
</catalog>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help ! as i stated in my previous comment to the other reply i have a few questions if that's ok for you : 
1) There is something else that i should do because the "headerNode" can be more than one node.. how would it be possible to copy all the nodes that goes from the beginning of the root till the "book" node ? (same for footerNode)
2) Since the "book" node is not defined and can change, how can we make it generic and input the name of the split node when executing the script ?
3) How can i write (the generated xml files) in a folder and not in the project ?

Comment: Hi! 1) here I've used findall to get the headernode and footernode and hence even if there are more than one, all such nodes will be fetched! 2) 'book' node is not defined? I don't get it.do you mean the element name name be anything else other than book or a specific set of name? Like 'book' 'novel' etc. If that is the case you can store the possible tag names into a list and check is the elem.tag in li(the list that contains all possible book tag names) or elem.tag not in['headerNode','footerNode','catalog']

Comment: 3) to write th result to a file in different folder  modify the write method to hold the file path.. write('path/to/folder/'+elem.get('id')+'.xml','wb')

Comment: thank you for your comment ! By my "book node is not defined", i meant that that it would be "book" or something else like "novel","paper", etc.. so i left it to the user to input it as a parameter to the script when executing it.
What is left for me to do is implement the generic solution for "headerNode"/"footerNode" as MK Ultra suggested in his comment. Good day !

Comment: I've added the edits! Hope it helps!

Comment: This is really helpful ! Thanks a lot ! So there is just a little issue i can't solve (i think it's the same problem so i did not create a new question for this), when creating the splitted files I can't make it to copy the attributes of the node "catalog" (just modified this node to have attributes, you can refer to my EDIT2), in fact in the splitted file it creates the catalog node without attributes.. hope its clear ! Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: I seriously suggest to try the above(my answer) code for your functionality. I couldnt really figure out the run time arguments that you give for the snippet youve share in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head you can do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load the xml
doc = ET.parse(r"d:\books.xml")
root = doc.getroot()
# Get the header element
header = root.find("headerNode")
# Get the footer element
footer = root.find("footerNode")
# loop over the books and create the new xml file
for book in root.findall('book'):
    top = ET.Element(root.tag)
    top.append(header)
    top.append(book)
    top.append(footer)
    out_book = ET.ElementTree(top)
    # the output file name will be the ID of the book
    out_path = "%s.xml" % book.attrib["id"]
    out_book.write(open(out_path, "wb"))
```

Comment: Good ! This does the trick ! However, i have some questions if you don't mind : 
1) There is something else that i should do because the "headerNode" can be more than one node.. how would it be possible to copy all the nodes that goes from the beginning of the root till the "book" node ? (same for footerNode)
2) Since the "book" node is not defined and can change, how can we make it generic and input the name of the split node when executing the script ?
3) How can i write (the generated xml files) in a folder and not in the project ?

Comment: Hi, what you can do is to loop over all elements under the root, add all the elements which are not "book" elements into a new Element object (same as in the above example). once you did that you have xml with all the elements which are not book. then loop over all the books elements and one by one add them to the template, save to file and remove from the template (similar to the solution provided by Keerthana Prabhakaran

Comment: Thanks again for the help ! I will try to do what you suggest and implement the code.. i'll let you know if it work ! (or not ^^)