# Split Textdocument by Variable(s) and Name new Files based on specific String

Tags: python, xml, batch-file, split

i have a textdocument with elements like header and body etc.
example:

Project.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">

<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>name</name>
        <description>description</description>
    </header>
    <master name="Project1">
        <description>Project1</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
    <master name="Project2">
        <description>Project2</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
    <master name="Project3">
        <description>Project3</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
</datafile>
```

i am trying to copy the header, but replacing the `<name>value</name>` to the value of the `<master name="value">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">

<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>Project1</name>
        <description>description</description>
    </header>
```

and cut/paste each "master" tag:

```
<master name="Project1">
    <description>Project1</description>
    <slave name="random information"/>
    <slave name="random information"/>
</master>
```

and also append the closing  tag

```
</datafile>
```

together this three parts merge into one new document. the filename should be taken from the "master name" tag. in that case its "Project1".

so basically the output would be three files like this:

Project1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">

<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>Project1</name>
        <description>description</description>
    </header>
    <master name="Project1">
        <description>Project1</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
</datafile>
```

Project2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">

<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>Project2</name>
        <description>description</description>
    </header>
    <master name="Project2">
        <description>Project2</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
</datafile>
```

Proejct3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">

<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>Project3</name>
        <description>description</description>
    </header>
    <master name="Project3">
        <description>Project3</description>
        <slave name="random information"/>
        <slave name="random information"/>
    </master>
</datafile>
```

also the project names can have spaces in their values.

sadly i dont have any real code so far. i only know how to find and copy specific parts with notepad++. but thats it -.-

so i am more than thankful for any help. the kind of method doesnt matter for me. it can be batchfile, python or anything else. thanks

oh and if this could be done as a loop for multiple documents, than that would be even more perfect :)

Comment: are you on Windows?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes windows 7

Comment: i forgot to mention, for the splitted files i also want the <name>value</name> in the header replaced by the master name=value.

Comment: @LotPings: The `batch-file` tag have the same relevance of the `python` one in this question. Perhaps you should explain why you think the `batch-file` tag is not relevant after a Batch file answer was already posted...

Comment: @Aacini Sorry but `after` is plain wrong if you look at the time stamps. As  tartaro himself posts a python answer I don't think my removing of the batch-file tag was without reason. And we don't need a discussion on the suitability of batch to handle xml files with utf8 encoding properly (or at all).

Comment: @LotPings but my question was not explicitly related to python. i just happened to find a similar question that was seeking for an answer in python. if the solution for my question would be a batchfile, i would gladly make use of it :) thanks anyway

Comment: @tartaro I apologize for removing the tag you consider fitting. If your file with utf-8 encoding contains any chars outside of the ascii set they might get mangled, python OTOH has no problems with this encoding.

Comment: @LotPings no need for apologizing :) if a batchfile cant handle utf-8 encoding well, then it might be better to stick to python, which does handle the encoding better, right. thanks for the clarification. though i am still looking for the last piece of my questions answer :). the answer i have found and posted here is not yet complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a dynamic [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) script, the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python can run XSLT 1.0 using the third-party module, `lxml`. Since you require slight modification and splitting of the document, this approach can do both.

Below iterates through the length of `<master>` nodes and passes index iteratively with `str.format()` (see curly brace placeholders), saving output to name attrib files: *Project 1.xml, Project 2.xml, Project 3.xml*. Because XSLT scripts are XML files, it can be parsed from string or file with `etree`.

```
import lxml.etree as et

doc = et.parse('C:\\1\\Project.xml')

xslstr = '''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/datafile">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="header"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="master[{0}]"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:copy>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::datafile/master[{0}]/@name"/></name>
       <xsl:copy-of select="description"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

for i in range(1,len(doc.xpath('//master'))+1):
    # PARSE XSLT
    xsl = et.fromstring(xslstr.format(i))

    # TRANFORM INPUT TO OUTPUT
    transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
    result = transform(doc)

    # SAVE OUTPUT
    outfile = doc.xpath('//master[{}]/@name'.format(i))[0] + '.xml'
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

To iterate through multiple XML files in same directory, wrap the needed code in a loop:

```
import os 
import lxml.etree as et

dir = "C:\\Path\\To\\XML\\Files"

# LOOP THROUGH FILES IN DIRECTORY
for f in os.listdir(dir):
    if f.endswith('.xml'):

        # PARSE XML
        doc = et.parse(os.path.join(dir, f))

        for i in range(1,len(doc.xpath('//master'))+1):
            # PARSE XSLT (same xslstr as above -no need to loop it)
            xsl = et.fromstring(xslstr.format(i))

            # TRANFORM INPUT TO OUTPUT
            transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
            result = transform(doc)

            # SAVE OUTPUT
            outfile = doc.xpath('//master[{}]/@name'.format(i))[0] + '.xml'
            with open(os.path.join(dir, outfile), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(result)
```

Comment: so i installed "Windows X86-64 MSI Installer (2.7.0) [1] (sig)" and "lxml-3.8.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe (md5)"

then i placed your script in a file called "strip.py" along the xml file i want to strip. i started the script and got some text in console:
`C:\1>C:\1\1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1\1.py", line 3, in <module>
    doc = et.parse('C:\1\Project.xml')
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3442, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:81716)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1811, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:118635)`


etc..

Comment: That's not the full traceback. Show the last few lines containing a useful message. This script parses the source file at an absolute path using your own posted answer: `'C:\1\Project.xml'`.

Comment: cant post all 'cause of char-limit,here the last lines:
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1138, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:112440)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105896)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:107604)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106415)
IOError: Error reading file 'C:☺\Project.xml': failed to load external entity "C:☺/Project.xml"

Comment: Whoops! You use the raw string `r"..."`. We need to double the backslashes! See edit.

Comment: that works well now. but is it possible to keep the lines before `<datafile>` original? i mean just copying them? these one: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC"">`

Comment: also what is the variable for a file that i would drag and drop on the script? i dont know python. 

i mean this part: "doc = et.parse('C:\\1\\Project.xml')" <--what variable would i put in there so that the file i drag and drop on the script is automatically recognized as the input file?

Comment: For *DOCTYPE* in your posted example, it is not well formed. It fails online xml validators. Did you omit something? You can add the doctype back by placing it in the `<xsl:output ... >`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676171/doctype-declaration-getting-lost-when-using-xsl).

Comment: And not sure what you mean by drag and drop? .py files are text files like any other scripts and not user interface tools. How are you running the Python script? We can pass command line arguments. But that may be another question to ask.

Comment: i use it by copying the code into a textdocument and changing its extension to .py then i doubleclick it. 
what i ask for is a way to use this script of yours on multiple files without manually changing the import path in the code. thats what i meant by drag and drop. i know from batchfile that you can use %1 as a variable for files that are dropped on the batchfile.

Comment: You can iterate through a list of directory files in Python. Stackoverflow has many, many questions on how to do so. So in this solution wrap the bottom loop within another loop that iterates through XML files, changing *doc* each time.

Comment: not quite helpful the last answer. but anyway thanks

Comment: Does your multiple XML files reside in same folder? See my extended answer showing how to loop through a directory of XML files. Notice now *doc* is variable with each iteration.

Comment: i can put them in the same folder if necessary. right now they are in one directory but each xml in a subdirectory. 
also i am not quite sure how wrapping the loops works -.-
do i just append the second loop to the first one?

Comment: Please see my edited answer and read on looping, a general concept in computer programming.

Comment: i know what loop is. i use it in batchfiles. this is my first time with python script. so please could you clarify what i have to do with your code to get the desired result here?

Comment: Just change `dir = "C:\\Path\\To\\XML\\Files"` to actual path of all xml files.

Comment: sorry if i cant express myself well enough. i also know that part. what i dont understand is how i put both of your code postings together in one python script. do i copy both in one file. or how does the final result look like. could you please post one complete example of how the final script would look like if the path of the multiple xml files is: "C:\1\"

Comment: The bottom block will work sufficiently, just move over the multiline *xslstr* string including the triple quotes (which I comment in code) to the top outside the loop and change path. Double up any backslashes.

Comment: please look at my edited answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017364/6152159 and see the result i get. the code is not working right now. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SO is not a free coding service. You must show your own efforts in order to get any help. However, I am doing an exception in this case...

The Batch file below do the file split you requested over one .xml file. However, it is very simple to modify this code in order to process several `*.xml` files, but you must do your own research to do that (tip: it requires a `for` command combined with a `dir` one).

**EDIT**: I added the *new requirement* of insert the name of each project in the `<name>` tag.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :SplitFile < Project.xml
goto :EOF


:SplitFile

rem First part: extract the header until first "<master" line
del Header.xml 2>NUL
:Header
set "line="
set /P "line="
if not defined line echo/>> Header.xml & goto Header
if "!line:master=!" equ "!line!" (
   if "!line:name=!" neq "!line!" (
      for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=<>" %%a in ("!line!") do set "line=%%a<%%b>^!file^!<%%d>"
   )
   echo !line!>> Header.xml
   goto Header
)

rem Second part: extract each "<master" section into its own file
set "files="
:Master0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==>" %%a in ("!line!") do set "file=%%~a"
set "files=%files% %file%"
(
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Header.xml) do echo/%%a
echo !line!
) > %file%.xml
:Master1
set "line="
set /P "line="
if not defined line echo/>> %file%.xml & goto Master1
if "!line:master=!" equ "!line!" echo !line!>> %file%.xml & goto Master1
echo !line!>> %file%.xml
:Master2
set "line="
set /P "line="
if not defined line goto Master2
if "!line:master=!" neq "!line!" goto Master0

rem Third part: add the last line to all files
for %%a in (%files%) do echo !line!>> %%a.xml
del Header.xml

exit /B
```

Comment: thanks, the <master name> element can have spaces in it. like "Project [Alpha] Part2"
@Aacini
do i need to put some variables in quotation mark?

Comment: i will be able to make a loop batch out of it, if it works for the one file first :)

Comment: i tested it and i first had to add quotations around all variables after echo with .xml in it. like > "%file%.xml" etc..
after that i progressed the main Project.xml file with the batchfile.
the first xml file generated from the first master is generated up until the </datafile> closing tag. which is missing. the next project is missing the xml eclaration and the header. it directly starts with machine name etc. and even further projects are even more missing. the filename also breaks somewhere later on. and the internal name tag in the header does not change at all

Comment: Why is a batch script placed on a python-tagged question? While I do welcome and do so myself special-purpose scripting like sql and xslt, you may need to show OP and future readers how the general-purpose language (here, Python) can run such files, maybe an intro of what they are!

Answer (score 0):

i found a similar question here and made use of this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436949/6152159

i changed the code to my requirements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load the xml
doc = ET.parse(r"C:\1\Project.xml")
root = doc.getroot()
# Get the header element
header = root.find("header")
# loop over the masters and create the new xml file
for master in root.findall('master'):
    top = ET.Element(root.tag)
    top.append(header)
    top.append(master)
    out_master = ET.ElementTree(top)
    # the output file name will be the ID of the master
    out_path = "%s.xml" % master.attrib["name"]
    out_master.write(out_path, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

this generates splitted xml files with the correct filename from the master.attrib["name"]. i now only need to find a way to replace the `<name>value</name>` in the header, to also use the master.attrib["name"] value.

*EDIT: i will paste the code from Parfait here that i am using right now:

```
import os 
import lxml.etree as et

dir = "C:\\1\\"

xslstr = '''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/datafile">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="header"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="master[{0}]"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:copy>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::datafile/master[{0}]/@name"/></name>
       <xsl:copy-of select="description"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

# LOOP THROUGH FILES IN DIRECTORY
for f in os.listdir(dir):
    if f.endswith('.xml'):

        for i in range(1,len(doc.xpath('//master'))+1):
            # PARSE XML
            doc = et.parse(os.path.join(dir, f))

            # PARSE XSLT (same xslstr as above -no need to loop it)
            xsl = et.fromstring(xslstr.format(i))

            # TRANFORM INPUT TO OUTPUT
            transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
            result = transform(doc)

            # SAVE OUTPUT
            outfile = doc.xpath('//master[{}]/@name'.format(i))[0] + '.xml'
            with open(os.path(dir, outfile), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(result)
```

this results in:

```
C:\1>C:\1\strip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1\strip.py", line 29, in <module>
    for i in range(1,len(doc.xpath('//machine'))+1):
NameError: name 'doc' is not defined
```

Comment: In your post, do you even show the desired output of this last request?

Comment: Whoops! Move `doc = ...` line to outer loop before the second `for`. See my edit.

Comment: i get: C:\1>C:\1\strip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1\strip.py", line 42, in <module>
    with open(os.path(dir, outfile), 'wb') as f:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Whoops again! Add *join*: `os.path.join(dir, outfile)`. See my edit.

Comment: @Parfait amazing, this really progresses multiple files in one predefined working directory. now the last puzzle piece, how to do the same for multiple files in the same working directory, but each in a subdirectory. how do make this recursive? thats my final request here. thanks in advance sir :)

Comment: Look into python's `os.walk()` which iterates through all dirs and subdirs.